# Queuing PHP processes

Tags: php, shell-exec

I've got the following two files in my server

1. `requests.php` (controller) - receives incoming requests and executes `process_query.php` in the background.
2. `process_query.php` - contains a script which calls a `C` executable (using `shell_exec`) to run against a certain number of files and writes some information to the database.

Right now as soon as the server receives a request in the controller, it immediately triggers the `process_query.php` script in the background. If there are too many incoming requests, it may result in server CPU outage. So I planned to have a max. limit to number of `process_query.php` processes that can run at a particular instant. For an example, let's assume the max. limit is 4 which implies only 4 instances of `process_query.php` can run at a time and others cannot start until one of the 4 processes finish.

I tried implementing this by having a table with `request_id`'s and a `flag` to indicate process completion status. If there are 4 requests running right now then the table will have 4 entries with status `flag` as `0` in each.

When a new request arrives the `process_query.php` script runs into an infinite loop as shown in the code below and checks in the database for the total number of processes running at the moment. Since it is 4 as per our scenario, the script goes to sleep state (eg.`10s`). The loop keeps executing for every `10s` until one of the process is completed. When the condition is met, the script comes out of the loop and performs the `C` call. After implementing this, I expected my activity monitor to show only 4 processes running. Unlikely there were n (total number of requests) processes running as the infinite loop kept the `process_query.php` process ticking. It made sense to me.

`process_query.php`

```
while(1) {
    $req_count = execute("SELECT count(status) FROM `requests` WHERE status=0");
    if($req_count == $max_request_limit) {
        sleep(10);
        continue;
    } 
    break;
}

// ...code to execute the C script

// end of process_query.php
```

Which approach should I adapt in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a job manager like `gearman`.

Explanation:

- there is a job server, with a list of the jobs to do
- there are `workers`, which are programms registered to that server in order to treat a job
- there are `clients`, which are the programms that requested a job to be done with some parameters.

Imagine that you have a job server, you will have to write:

- a worker: `myworker.php` in which you call process_query.php, and you register to the job 'process_query'
- a client: in requests.php, you do a call to launch the job 'process_query' with some parameters

Then you will launch myworker.php 5 times (in background), and so you have maximum 5 jobs in process, the others will wait until one worker is available.

You can either launch a job from requests.php in an asynchronous way, either with a synchronous way (to wait until the job ends).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `gearman`. I wish to implement it on a long term basis as I do not sufficient privileges on the server to install it right now. Is there a `PHP` centric solution without installing any external packages? bcoz I need to make it up and running in next two days or so.

Comment: The problem in your sql solution is that there is no guarantee that $max_request_limit will be == to req count. You have to use >= but you may have lots of requests.  Another way would be to use "file mutex", there is an implementation here https://code.google.com/p/mutex-for-php/  , it allows you to create a file and when you finish, it is removed and then the second process now create the file and execute its code, etc..